Logistic regression sample size with categorical predictor in G power
I am trying to figure out if G power is the way to go in my case and if I am doing it right. I wish to calculate a priori sample size.
I am about to do a cohort study using registry data using logistic regression with a binary outcome of disease yes/no. However my predictor (x) has 3 categories/groups. From what Ive understand I should "see these" as 2 variables (one reference). These groups might also not be evenly balanced.
Also, I might have up to 7 other covariables.
My questions:
Is this possible with G power and if so..
How do I set my "x parm" for uneven groups when there are 3?
The x distribution is still binominal even with predictor which has several categories?
The only way to account for the covariables is using "R2 other x"? Or is there any other way/application which does this better?
In my testrun with an effect size of OR 1.27 (I wish to detect an 2% ARR). Still with evenly matched groups. I would need 6703 patients, seems high? Or perhaps correct due to such small difference? With x distribution "normal" or "poisson" sample size is much lower.

